# Regex in Javascript to match repeated alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I need Regex in Javascript to match repeated alphabet.

I want to spot a repeated letter in a string using regex.
And also split around them.

```
 var str = "aabbcde";
 str.split(/[a-z](?=$1)/g)
```

but it still returns the whole string.
I want to split ["aabbcde"]. How do I make regex pattern to match repeated letters? What I tried is to match any one alphabet first and the one that follows from the match using (?= regex. But it does not wokr. Any idea? Thanks a lot

My desire output would be

```
 var str = "aabbcde";
 str.split(/[a-z](?=$1)/g)
 // output = ["aa", "bb", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: Would be easier if you post the desired output along with the code too.

Comment: How to you want this string to be splitted?

Comment: I did add the output. THanks~!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to surround the regular expression with `()` to make a group. And use `\1` to backreference the group (instead of `$1`. `$1` is can be used in replacement string in `replace` method).

```
var str = "aabbcde";
str.match(/([a-z])\1*/g)
// => ["aa", "bb", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: Beat me to it and in a cleaner way, +1.

Comment: powerful! I didn't know that match can also do the split thing

Comment: @Robert Keenan: `match` doesn't split - it matches